# If random variable $Y$ represents the number of heads in a 3 fair coin toss what does $Y^2$ represent?

Tags: probability, random-variables

The random variable $Y$ takes on one of the values 0, 1, 2, and 3 with respective probabilities

$P\{Y=0\}=P\{(T,T,T)\}=1/8$

$P\{Y=1\}=P\{(T,T,H),(T,H,T),(H,T,T)\}=3/8$

$P\{Y=2\}=P\{(T,H,H),(H,T,H),(H,H,T)\}=3/8$

$P\{Y=3\}=P\{(H,H,H)\}=1/8$

What does it mean to say $Y^2$ and What will be its distribution and how is it calculated ? Arithmetic on probability page of wikipedia did not help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by " what does it mean to says $Y^2$" ? It's just a random variable that depend on $Y$... If you want an interpretation, say that it will be the area of the square of side $Y$.

---

**Hint**

For the distribution of $Y^2$, notice that $$\{Y^2=k\}=\{Y\in \{-\sqrt k,\sqrt k\}\}.$$ So, for example $$\mathbb P\{Y^2=9\}=\mathbb P\{Y=3\}.$$

Comment: May be this is what i am missing $\{Y^2=k\}=\{Y\in \{-\sqrt k,\sqrt k\}\}.$  On what basis this equation is derived. Does this mean $P\{Y^2=1\}=3/8,$ $P\{Y^2=2\}=3/8$. I am following sheldon ross book "A first course on probabilty" and i am at a loss when it comes to arithmetic on random variables , i posted a similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3616836/multiplication-of-random-variables . Any recommended books or sources to learn the arithmetic on probability ?  Thanks

Comment: For your first question, because $Y^2=k\iff Y=\sqrt k$. After $\mathbb P\{Y^2=2\}=\mathbb P\{Y\in \{\sqrt{-2},\sqrt 2\}\}=0$ (and not what you wrote). But $$\mathbb P\{Y^2=4\}=\mathbb P\{Y\in \{-2,2\}\}=\mathbb P\{Y=2\}=3/8.$$ @Talespin_Kit